# returning extra column with formatted date

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a schema(table) like following in seqluelize:

```
    const schema = sequelize.define("order_entry_header", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        date: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        sub_total: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        },
        ...
    });
```

My requirement is whenever I call or use or include this schema `order_entry_header` in
any place in my app I want `date` column in to format in a readable text in a different column called `date_format`

In simple sql this should be something like below:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    date,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d/%m/%Y") as date_format
    ...
FROM order_entry_header;
```

I am joining/fetching this table data in numerous places and every-time I have to add extra column to get the formatted date specifically. I want this to be automated.

.
.

With `instanceMethod` it can be performed. but I have to call the method every-time I get the data which is a little confusing sometimes.

.
.

Is there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Default scope` (see [Scopes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html))

```
const schema = sequelize.define("order_entry_header", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        date: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        sub_total: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        },
        ...
    }, {
         defaultScope: {
          attributes: [{ include: [[Sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT', Sequelize.col('date')), 'date_format']]}]
      active: true
    }
  }
});
```